# issue in testing html file with javascript jasmine

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jasmine

I have an html file with D3.js javascript library. I want to test it with jasmine. my question is that I must have `.js` suffix or I can also test html files with jasmine.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that it is possible to test html files with jasmine (btw. jasmine is great!).

But what exactly do you want to test?

- The D3.js library?
  --> do not unit-test external libs
- some js Functions used within your html
  --> extract them in a separate js-file and include that in your html
  or
- the structure of your generated html?
  --> use an browser test automation e.g. selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can't test html files directly but you can load fixtures using [jasmine-fixture](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-fixture) or [jasmine-dom](https://github.com/jeffwatkins/jasmine-dom)